# Getting a specific data from a json file using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, elasticsearch

Hi I have a json file and I want to extract some data from it
the file looks like as below:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 4.0201406,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "catalogue",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "p95iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT",
        "_score" : 4.0201406,
        "_source" : {
          "categorie" : "Bonbons ",
          "marque" : "TIC TAC",
          "nom" : "bonbon duo TIC TAC"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "catalogue",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "od5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT",
        "_score" : 3.6080353,
        "_source" : {
          "categorie" : "Bonbons",
          "marque" : "TIC TAC",
          "nom" : "Bonbons duo de fraises TIC TAC"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the result of elasticserch query and my question is how can I retrieve the  categorie, marque,nom and their values from this file using php?.
I tried to convert this result to an array,I used json_decode() but I always got null then I used Service_json() and I solve the problem.
After that, I got this result but now I have a difficulty to get some specific data like categorie,nom, marque and their values and I got empty result.
this is my php code:

```
array(1) {
  ["hits"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["hits"]=>
    array(7) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "kN5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(29) "Bonbons parfums fruits MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "kd5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#7 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(21) "Bonbons menthe MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "kt5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(37) "Bonbons caramel/chocolat blanc MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "k95iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "Mentos"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(31) "Bonbons caramel/chocolat MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      object(stdClass)#12 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "lN5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#13 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(28) "Bonbons menthe sucres MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      object(stdClass)#14 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "ld5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#15 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(31) "Bonbons framboise orange MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [6]=>
      object(stdClass)#16 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "lt5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(26) "Bonbons pomme verte MENTOS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What data are you trying to extract from the JSON exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**[1. Response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering)**

> filter_path parameter that can be used to reduce the response returned
>   by Elasticsearch. This parameter takes a comma separated list of
>   filters expressed with the dot notation:

ex. filter_path=hits.hits._source

**[2. Source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-source-filtering.html#search-request-source-filtering)**

_source: can be used to specify which fields are to be returned. By default all fields are returned

```
GET <index_name>/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "_source": ["categorie","marque","nom"]
}
```

**Result**

```
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "categorie" : "Bonbons",
          "nom" : "Bonbons pomme verte MENTOS",
          "marque" : "MENTOS"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.Your answer was helpful
now when I parse this data after I convert it  into an array using php I got an empty result

Comment: @Ana Can you add your php query in question

Comment: @Ana I am not aware of php sytnax. From documents I gathered it should be something like below $params = [
    'index' => 'my_index','filter_path':"hits.hits._source"
    'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'testField' => 'abc'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$results = $client->search($params);

$doc   = $results['hits']['hits'][0]['_source'];

Comment: @Ana Glad could be of help